# Tomcat does not recognize the MySQL .jar library

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I tried several different ways such that Tomcat loads the MySQL drivers when running my web application. I'm using Ubuntu 8.04, and the libraries come from the libmysql-java package. They are located in the directory shown below:

```
~$ ls /usr/share/java/mysql*
/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.5.jar
```

My CLASSPATH includes this file:

```
~$ echo $CLASSPATH
.:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin:/usr/local/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.5.jar
```

I even put a copy of the .jar file in my WEB-INF/lib/ directory in my web app:

```
/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ohms/WEB-INF/lib$ ls
mysql-connector-java-5.1.5.jar
```

After making these changes, I restart Tomcat, re-compile my classes, restart Tomcat again. Also, I am importing the necessary libraries using `import java.sql.*;`

However I am still getting the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` error when it runs the line `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Put it in TOMCAT_HOME/lib. (I seem to recall that on older versions of Tomcat, it's TOMCAT_HOME/server/lib?)

It's not going to work in WEB-INF/lib since the container needs access to the library, and, that is putting it in the classloader of one web app, not the container. While I would have imagined the CLASSPATH approach would work, it's not the standard way to do this. Perhaps there is some other snag that's preventing it from working.

Comment: Added `java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.5.jar` to `/usr/local/tomcat/lib/`, still no dice.

Comment: Not java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.5.jar. Just add the mysql-connector-java-5.1.5.jar directly under /usr/local/tomcat/lib.

Comment: that's what i meant, it was a typo

Comment: also, i even tried downloading the latest version of mysql-connector frome the official site, putting it under tomcat/lib, and removing any other references to the library.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat ignores any CLASSPATH environment variable, as do all Java EE app servers and IDEs.  That does you no good at all. I don't set one on any machine that I use.

The JAR needs to go in Tomcat server/lib for Tomcat 5.x and /lib for 6.x.

You don't need to call newInstance(); Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") is sufficient to register the driver class.

Comment: To be precise, it's default startup scripts (e.g. `catalina.sh`) that ignore (or, rather, override) CLASSPATH rather than Tomcat itself. I've seen RPMs where that was not the case; don't know whether one that comes with Ubuntu 8.04 distribution is one of those. The resulting classpath is used by Tomcat's system class loader.

Comment: Correct.  That's been my experience with Tomcat, WebLogic, JBOSS, IntelliJ, and Eclipse.  None take a system CLASSPATH into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Copy mysql connector to /usr/share/tomcat7/lib

Answer (score 1):

One other thing you might want to do, if you don't want to put a file into the Tomcat lib directory.  It states in catalina.sh that it will check setenv.sh for a variable set to include outside jars.  So for example, as I did it, you may create this file:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh
```

with the contents:

```
CLASSPATH=lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar
```

The path to the jar will be relative to where you start up Tomcat, also known as your working directory.  So, for example, in my case I start up Catalina from an Ant script two levels up from $CATALINA_HOME and my lib directory is directly underneath that point.